# angularJS passing $scope variable to a ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `input type=text` linked to `ng-model="queryText"`. Now I wrote a function to build a url from the `queryText` and then another function that takes this url and calls an external (wikipedia) API.

Nothing happens when I click the submit button (no http get, no response, no error), and I can't figure out if I'm passing in my arguments correctly. Basically what I want to do, is to pass the result of the `makeUrl()` function into the `searchArticle()` when a user submits a query.

my html:

```
<div ng-app="wikiView">
  <div ng-controller="wikiController">
    <form novalidate>
      <input type=text ng-model="queryText">
      <input type="submit" ng-click="searchArticle(makeUrl('queryText'))" value="search">
    </form>
    {{ articles }}
    {{ error }}
  </div>
</div>
```

my app:

```
(function() {
  var wikiView = angular.module('wikiView', []);

  wikiView.controller('wikiController', function($scope, $http) {

    var onArticleReceived = function(response) {
      $scope.articles = response;
    }

    var onArticleError = function(reason) {
      $scope.error = reason;
    }

    $scope.queryText = "";

    var makeUrl = function(searchTerm) {
      return 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&maxlag=10&prop=&list=&meta=&titles=' + searchTerm;
    }

    var searchArticle = function(url) {
      $http.get(url)
        .then(onArticleReceived, onArticleError);
    }

  });
}());
```

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/shooshte/pen/NxQGQE) of the thing.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this work?[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMKXEz?editors=1011)

Comment: must create $scope function  for searchArticle.

Comment: Yes, added that in the answer and updated the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your code.

First, remove the single quotes around the `queryText`, since you want to pass an object and not the raw string:

```
 ng-click="searchArticle(makeUrl(queryText))"
```

Then, you need `searchArticle` and `makeUrl` available to the scope. So, use:

```
 $scope.makeUrl = function(){...}
```

instead of

```
var makeUrl = ...
```

These two changes will make your code work.

Here is a working codePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMKXoz

---

You could also simply use something like:

```
 ng-click="doStuff()"
```

and define `doStuff` as

```
  $scope.doStuff = function(){
      searchArticle(makeUrl($scope.queryText));
  }
```

which will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your codepen, is this the expected behaviour: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPqyRx

Changes:

`searchArticle` is now on $scope and calls `makeUrl` itself:

```
$scope.searchArticle = function(searchTerm) {
    var url = makeUrl(searchTerm);
    $http.get(url)
    .then(onArticleReceived, onArticleError);
}
```

And the template only calls `searchArticle()` now:

```
ng-click="searchArticle('queryText')" value="search">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your **HTML** as follows:

```
  <input type=text ng-model="queryText">
  <input type="submit" ng-click="searchArticle(makeUrl())" value="search">
```

and in the **AngularJS**

```
$scope.makeUrl = function() {
      console.log("Called");
      x= 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&maxlag=10&prop=&list=&meta=&titles=' + $scope.queryText;
      console.log(x);
      return x;
    }

    $scope.searchArticle = function(url) {
      console.log(url);
      $http.get(url)
        .then(onArticleReceived, onArticleError);
    }
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMKXEz?editors=1011)

Answer (score 0):

Neither your `makeUrl` nor your `searchArticle` functions were set on `$scope`, and you didn't need to have `queryText` in single quotes in the html (or else it just runs a search for 'queryText'). [Forked codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yemJEZ?editors=1010). It's running the query now, but it won't return the data to codepen because:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&maxlag=10&prop=&list=&meta=&titles=habit. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to attach your functions to the $scope object. Here is the complete HTML and JS after fix. To simplify I have removed makeURL function and added URL directly in searchArticle function

HTML

```
<div ng-app="wikiView">
  <div ng-controller="wikiController">
    <form novalidate>
      <input type=text ng-model="queryText">
      <input type="submit" ng-click="searchArticle()" value="search">
    </form>
    {{ articles }}
    {{ error }}
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function() {
  var wikiView = angular.module('wikiView', []);

  wikiView.controller('wikiController', function($scope, $http) {

    var onArticleReceived = function(response) {
        $scope.articles = response;
    }

    var onArticleError = function(reason) {
        $scope.error = reason;
    }

    $scope.queryText = "";

    $scope.searchArticle = function(url) {

        $http.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&maxlag=10&prop=&list=&meta=&titles=' + $scope.queryText)
             .then(onArticleReceived, onArticleError);
    }

  });
}());
```